# Php namespace herdar "use" de outra classe

Tags: php, namespace

Seria possível "herdar" *importações*, *use* de uma classe?
Exemplo

**Carro.php**

```
<?php

namespace app\model;

use app\Utils;
use app\Banco;

class Carro{}
```

main.php

```
<?php

namespace app\model;

use app\Carro;

class Main{
    $banco= new Banco();
}
```

Teria alguma forma de isso ser possível? Já que a classe *Carro* já tem um *use* para "Banco".

Comment: Não, `use` não importa a classe. Se precisa usá-la de novo, não há motivos plausíveis para não utilizar o `use` novamente.

Answer (score 0):

Não, namespaces são apenas para referenciar e localizar o objeto dentro de sua estrutura de código não tendo porquê haver herança ou qualquer regra de negócio para o mesmo.

Caso precise utilizar os mesmos métodos e ou funções de uma outra classe pai dai você entra no conceito de herança, neste caso também poderá utilizar TRAITS no caso do php para inserir ações internamente na classe.